# Spacing within the excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I am trying to find out how I can control how an excerpt is displayed using PHP. How do I get it to render the html spacing within the post instead of just showing one big paragraph.Hope that makes sense.

Let me give you an example.

So my client has syndicated post and at the top of each post he wants to include a hyperlink to the actual author . Then there needs to be a line break then the actual excerpt of the content under it. Currently the excerpt just shows everything as one paragraph.

I have managed to enter some php code to render the hyperlink in the excerpt but stuck on how to not let the excerpt strip the spacing.

Comment: If you want to output post content as-is, but just cut at a certain point, probably the use of `the_content` in combination with `<!--more-->` quicktag is best choice. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: I don't want it to cut at a certain point, I just want the excerpt to not strip the html away.

Comment: Are you talking about an excerpt manually inserted when publishing the post? Or an excerpt that is automatically generated from the full post content? In this 2nd case the excerpt is just the full content cut at a certain point... I was referring to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excerpt stips all html tags, a feature that frustrates many. I have written a custom excerpt that stops the excerpt from stipping any html tags. It also breaks the excerpt after the sentence after the set amount of words. If you need to cut the excerpt at exact words, you will just need to modify my code.

You will first need to remove the original excerpt, and then register the new excerpt. To do this, add the following code in your functions.php

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Now for the custom excerpt. Add this below the code above

```
function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($pietergoosen_excerpt) {
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $pietergoosen_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $pietergoosen_excerpt ) {

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $pietergoosen_excerpt );
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $pietergoosen_excerpt);
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $pietergoosen_excerpt);

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                $pos = strrpos($pietergoosen_excerpt, '</');
                if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                $pietergoosen_excerpt = substr_replace($pietergoosen_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
                else
                // After the content
                $pietergoosen_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

            return $pietergoosen_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }
```

If you need just specific tags, you can use the code below. Just add the code below, and the delete the tags that you need stripped.

```
function pietergoosen_get_allowedtags() {
// Add custom tags to this string that will be used as allowed tags
    return '<head>,<title>,<base>,<link>,<meta>,<style>,<script>,<noscript>,<body>,<section>,<nav>,
    <article>,<aside>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>,<header>,<footer>,<address>,<main>,<p>,<hr>,
    <pre>,<blockquote>,<ol>,<ul>,<li>,<dl>,<dt>,<dd>,<figure>,<figcaption>,<div>,<a>,<em>,<strong>,
    <small>,<s>,<cite>,<q>,<dfn>,<abbr>,<data>,<time>,<code>,<var>,<samp>,<kbd>,<sub>,<sup>,<i>,<b>,
    <u>,<mark>,<ruby>,<rt>,<rp>,<bdi>,<bdo>,<span>,<br>,<wbr>,<ins>,<del>,<img>,<iframe>,<embed>,
    <object>,<param>,<video> ,<audio>,<source>,<track>,<canvas>,<map>,<area>,<svg>,<math>,<table>,
    <caption>,<colgroup>,<col>,<tbody>,<thead>,<tfoot>,<tr>,<td>,<th>,<form>,<fieldset>,<legend>,<label>,
    <input>,<button>,<select>,<datalist>,<optgroup>,<option>,<textarea>,<keygen>,<output>,<progress>,<meter>,
    <details>,<summary>,<menuitem>,<menu>'; 
}
```

Just add this line `$pietergoosen_excerpt = strip_tags($pietergoosen_excerpt, pietergoosen_get_allowedtags());` below this line `$pietergoosen_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $pietergoosen_excerpt);`

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Pieter I will give it a go and see what happens. Will update you. Do I have permission to use this on all my clients sites if it works for me?

Comment: All code given on WPSE is open to use and modify as you wish. So go ahead and use it as you wish

Comment: My pleasure, glad that helped

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but is there a way that I can strip images from this?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: This doesn't work with get_the_excerpt($id). It works as if no id was passed and reads the post we're in.

Answer (score 0):

The function [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) automatically converts linebreaks to paragraph tags. Assuming your CSS-styling is set up correctly, you can apply `wpautop` to any text with newlines and WordPress will automatically add paragraph tags.

`wpautop` is automatically added as a filter to `the_excerpt`, so this should actually be doen by default. Could you post the code you're using to display the excerpt?

Comment: Thanks Engelen. Do I add this anywhere within the Functions.php file? sorry php is so not my strong suit.

Comment: The excerpt stips html tags....

Comment: @DianeLaidlaw I've updated my answer; `wpautop` is automatically called on `the_excerpt` by default (if it's not removed by `remove_filter`). Please post the code you're using to display your excerpt.

Comment: This is where it gets complicated. I am using a WordPress Framework that allows me to click and drag elements onto a canvas and it auto generates the code for me. All I need to do is select options of whether I want it to display              excerpt or full post. Nevertheless I have created a child theme so I am assuming I will be able to have more control over how things are displayed if needed.

Comment: If we don't know what function is used to display the excerpt we can hardly help you, unfortunately.

Comment: okay thanks anyway I will have a look at the forums over at the framework.