# adjust the_excerpt based on template page

Tags: excerpt

How can I write conditions to adjust `the_excerpt` on different pages?

For example on my `page-products.php` page I want `the_excerpt` to be let's say `40`.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Is it `if` and `else` conditions to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

**You can add it straight to the template before the header in most cases...**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Products */ ?>
<?php 
  add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) {  return 10; }, 999);
  get_header(); 
?>
```

These should work as well if you'd rather put in `functions.php`:

**Method 2: In the loop**

```
$slug = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);
if('page-products.php' == $slug) {
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) { 
           return 20; 
        }, 999);    
}
```

**Method 3: Outside the loop**

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-products.php' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) { 
       return 20; 
    }, 999);
}
```

**This could also be used to [get the template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug)....**

```
global $post;
$template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',true);
```

**Or possibly even this (untested):**

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if ( is_page( array( 37, 'Products' ) ) ) {
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function( $length ) { 
           return 20; 
        }, 999);
    }
}, 1);
```

**Or as [seen here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139960/38123), you can create your own function to allow the excerpt length to be determined on a need to need basis by the amount of characters.**

```
function excerpt($limit) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).' ...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}
```

*The to display:*

```
<?php echo excerpt(50); ?>
```